# Show/Hide markers in the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When i click in a button, it provides me the markers that i have in database and draws a line with them.
What i need is a button to show the line and when i click again it removes the line.
Can someone help me?

The button:

```
function buttonLinhaBigDest(buttonLinhaBigDestDiv, map_canvas) {

// Control border
var buttonLinhaBigDestUI = document.createElement('div');
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.border = '1px solid #717B87';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.marginBottom = '5px';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.title = 'markers';
buttonLinhaBigDestDiv.appendChild(buttonLinhaBigDestUI);

// Control interior
var buttonLinhaBigDestText = document.createElement('div');
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.fontSize = '13px';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.lineHeight = '38px';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.paddingRight = '5px';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.innerHTML = 'markers';
buttonLinhaBigDestUI.appendChild(buttonLinhaBigDestText);

var listener = google.maps.event.addDomListener(buttonLinhaBigDestUI, 'click', function() {
  $.getJSON('/markers/', function(data) {
      var line_lat_lon = [];
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, line) {
                line_lat_lon.push(new google.maps.LatLng(line.latitude, line.longitude));
                var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: line_lat_lon,
                    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    map: map_canvas,
            });         
        });
      });
```

index.html:

```
var map_canvas;
var santaCatarina = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.666885236556496, -51.15083105000002);

function initialize(url) {       
var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: santaCatarina,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };    
var map_canvas = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var buttonLinhaBigDestDiv = document.createElement('div');
var l_big_dest = new buttonLinhaBigDest(buttonLinhaBigDestDiv, map_canvas);

buttonLinhaBigDestDiv.index = 1;
map_canvas.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(buttonLinhaBigDestDiv);


 } 
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

JSON file:

```
{"markers": [{"nome": "Passo Fundo", "longitude": "-52.71871618", "latitude": "-27.48408601", "sigla": "PFU", "nome_concessionaria": "ELETROSUL"}, {"nome": "Pato Branco", "longitude": "-52.67245134", "latitude": "-26.21026458", "sigla": "PTO", "nome_concessionaria": "COPEL"}, {"nome": "Porto Velho", "longitude": "-63.81863187", "latitude": "-8.797357069", "sigla": "PV", "nome_concessionaria": "ELETRONORTE"}, {"nome": "Santa Cruz1", "longitude": "-52.41756156", "latitude": "-29.75061037", "sigla": "SCR1", "nome_concessionaria": "CEEE"}
```

Comment: Call .clear() to remove polyline

Comment: But how can i click in the same button and it execute the other function?

Comment: I think you can put your `polyline` or `marker` to an `ArrayList` or `HashMap`, so you can call `.remove()`, or get the `polyline`.

Comment: Yeah , but my doubt is not how im gonna clear the map, but how can i do this in the same button that i use to put the markers.

Comment: What is `map_canvas`?  What HTML/CSS is required to run the posted code? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `map_canvas` is just the name of my map. You can use the button as JS file and just create a map in the index.html file.

Comment: @geocodezip, i edited my index file. But what i need to know is how can i use the same button to hide/show the markers.

Comment: What is url in initialize(url)? That won't be assigned by the onload call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle the line, create a global variable to hold the reference then set its `map` property to null if it isn't already null:

```
var line;
var listener = google.maps.event.addDomListener(buttonLinhaBigDestUI, 'click', function () {
    if (line && line.setMap) { // toggle it
        if (line.getMap() != null) line.setMap(null);
        else line.setMap(map_canvas);
    } else { // make the line
        $.getJSON('/markers/', function (data) {
          var data = jsonData;
          var line_lat_lon = [];
          $.each(data.markers, function (i, line) {
            line_lat_lon.push(new google.maps.LatLng(line.latitude, line.longitude));
          });
          line = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: line_lat_lon,
            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            map: map_canvas
          });
        });
    }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1g61wxy/)

code snippet:

```js
function buttonLinhaBigDest(buttonLinhaBigDestDiv, map_canvas) {

    // Control border
    var buttonLinhaBigDestUI = document.createElement('div');
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.border = '1px solid #717B87';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.marginBottom = '5px';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.title = 'markers';
    buttonLinhaBigDestDiv.appendChild(buttonLinhaBigDestUI);

    // Control interior
    var buttonLinhaBigDestText = document.createElement('div');
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.fontSize = '13px';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.lineHeight = '38px';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.style.paddingRight = '5px';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.innerHTML = 'markers';
    buttonLinhaBigDestUI.appendChild(buttonLinhaBigDestText);

    var listener = google.maps.event.addDomListener(buttonLinhaBigDestUI, 'click', function () {
        if (line && line.setMap) { // toggle it
            if (line.getMap() != null) line.setMap(null);
            else line.setMap(map_canvas);
        } else { // make the line
            //$.getJSON('/markers/', function (data) {
            var data = jsonData;
            var line_lat_lon = [];
            $.each(data.markers, function (i, line) {
                line_lat_lon.push(new google.maps.LatLng(line.latitude, line.longitude));
            });
            line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: line_lat_lon,
                strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                map: map_canvas
            });
            // });
        }
    });
}
var jsonData = {
    "markers": [{
        "nome": "Passo Fundo",
            "longitude": "-52.71871618",
            "latitude": "-27.48408601",
            "sigla": "PFU",
            "nome_concessionaria": "ELETROSUL"
    }, {
        "nome": "Pato Branco",
            "longitude": "-52.67245134",
            "latitude": "-26.21026458",
            "sigla": "PTO",
            "nome_concessionaria": "COPEL"
    }, {
        "nome": "Porto Velho",
            "longitude": "-63.81863187",
            "latitude": "-8.797357069",
            "sigla": "PV",
            "nome_concessionaria": "ELETRONORTE"
    }, {
        "nome": "Santa Cruz1",
            "longitude": "-52.41756156",
            "latitude": "-29.75061037",
            "sigla": "SCR1",
            "nome_concessionaria": "CEEE"
    }]
};


var map_canvas;
var line;
var santaCatarina = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.666885236556496, -51.15083105000002);

function initialize(url) {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: santaCatarina,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map_canvas = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var buttonLinhaBigDestDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var l_big_dest = new buttonLinhaBigDest(buttonLinhaBigDestDiv, map_canvas);

    buttonLinhaBigDestDiv.index = 1;
    map_canvas.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(buttonLinhaBigDestDiv);


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```